# Cloud Run service killed with moderately-sized request body

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

A Cloud Run service crashes when it receives a request body above some limit between 1mb and 10mb and the server does not read the body.

I created and deployed a Cloud Run service in go, using the [Quickstart example](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-go-service).

If I make a POST request with a 10mb JSON body, the service is killed and the client receives a generic 500 response. I expect a 200 since I don't see any [documented limits](https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas) that apply.

Interestingly, if I update the sample code to read the request body in its entirety (`io.ReadAll(r.Body)`), then everything works as expected.

However, I'd like to be able to reject large requests with a 413 status without having to read the entire body.

This isn't specific to go; I experience the same behavior with the Node.js example.

Comment: Do you try to read the document or not? Do you build your container or do you let Cloud Run building it? Do you have additional layer on top of Cloud Run (Load Balancer,...)

Comment: When I read the body fully, the client receives a 200; when I don't (just using the supplied quickstart code), the service is killed. I didn't build the container — I used `gcloud run deploy` and it built from source. I have no additional layers and I'm requesting from *.run.app directly.

Comment: Interesting issue! And it fails only with large post content? or also with small size?

Comment: Only with larger sizes. A 1mb payload does not exhibit the problem. The problem seems to occur somewhere between 1 and 2mb.

Comment: Thanks, I will test and let you know

Comment: Were you able to work this out based on the suggestion and dicussion above. @bryfox.

Comment: I still experience this issue on any service I've created, including when building the image myself. I have not tried introducing GCP load balancing on top of the Cloud Run service.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning, I observed this in both generations of execution environment (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-execution-environments) and with higher memory & cpu limits configured (in addition to the defaults).